# Ratio of G/R+B value for each pixel in an image (python)

Tags: python, rgb

I am really new to Python programming

I wonder how could I extract the RGB value for each pixel, and then perform a simple calculation of G/R+B to get the 'greenness' of each single pixel?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What if `R=B=0`?